# Increment Version number when checking in to TFS

Tags: sql, visual-studio, tfs, version-control

I have a folder in TFS which has SQL Scripts.  At the moment I am manually adding a comment and updating a version number inside the comment every time i make a change and check it back it.  This works however was hoping there might be a better way. Is there a way to automate this in TFS?

I have read the following article
[Version control project files](https://www.richard-banks.org/2010/07/how-to-versioning-builds-with-tfs-2010.html)

do i have to go through such a process for simple .sql files? Are there any other simple ways.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this:

1. Create an automated build in TFS and write a custom build step / PowerShell script to parse the appropriate SQL scripts, read the version, increment it, and store the new version by either checking in the updated file or a local store
2. Use a database project (part of [SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686(v=VS.103).aspx)) which will output a DACPAC.  Inside the database project, you can set the version as specified [here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/573144/versioning-sql-server-databases-using-ssdt).  This stores the version in the project file.  If you update your TFS build number to be digits only, you can then update the project file to set that value to match the build using a custom build task.  For example, if your build number was yyyy.m.d.R where R is the number of times that build was run today (TFS manages that - it's the revision variable).  Or, you could set the the `<DacVersion>` tag to something like 2.1.0.0 and your build replaces the last digit with yyyymmddr.

I'd recommend using a database project.  It's pretty easy to [create a new database project off an existing database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272677(v=vs.103).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The first way mentioned by Jacob above can achieve that if you just want to incremental the version number of the script/folder, just create a CI build definition.

Actually you can just enable **Label sources** and set the **Label format** with predefined environment variables such as **$(build.buildNumber)**, and set without publish any artifacts during build process. 
Thus, it will automatically trigger the CI build when you check in files, and the source (SQL Script /folder) will be labeled with the incremental number.

Then you can find the specific versions with the label.
[image]